# Module Federation, Electron & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, webpack-module-federation

Is it possible to use module federation with electron? I am new to both and I'm unsure if the following code in webpack.config.js of the remote app makes sense since I'm using electron and not a regular web app that runs on localhost:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: `ejs-webpack-loader!src/renderer/index.ejs`,
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "MICRO",
      remotes: {
        FIRST_APP: "FIRST_APP@http://localhost:1212/remoteEntry.js",
      },
    }),
  ],
],
```

Will the remote App understand where FIRST_APP (host) is when I import it if I am using electron? It seems to find the path when not using electron.

This is how FIRST_APP is exposed in webpack.config.js of the host app:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: `ejs-webpack-loader!src/renderer/index.ejs`,
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "FIRST_APP",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./app": "./src/renderer/App",
      },
    }),
  ],
```

I followed the instructions as per this tutorial:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-microfrontend-in-react-in-3-easy-steps-74790fd0c9fb

When not using electron module federation functions as expected but when adding electron it fails to find the import statement from the remote app and gives the error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'FIRST_APP/app'"

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
const FirstApp = React.lazy(() => import("FIRST_APP/app")); //Is not finding this


const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is second app</h1>
      <h2>Micro host app is integrated here</h2>
      { name ? <p>Your name is: {name}</p> : null }
      <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
        <FirstApp />
      </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
I had trouble getting this to work using the out of the box react apps that are created when using npx create-react-app. I think there is some extra code that is provided that made it difficult to get module federation working with electron. I solved this by taking the following steps:

1. I followed this tutorial that explains how to setup module federation in a react app:
   https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-microfrontend-in-react-in-3-easy-steps-74790fd0c9fb
   This creates a react app from scratch and walks you through how to implement module federation by only adding the libraries that you need and nothing extra.
2. I upgraded the react app to use typescript. This is pretty straightforward and can be done by following react documentation.
3. I followed this tutorial to figure out how to add electron to both the host and remote apps and concurrently run react and electron:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_fROfS8FPE&ab_channel=zayne
   This allowed me to get electron working by only adding the libraries I need and nothing more.

I have found using out of the box react apps or the electron-react-boiler-plate repo provided by the electron documentation provided a lot of extra code that was causing issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).